# Computing $l(D)$ for certain divisor.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g=2$. I want to prove that there exist $P,Q\in C$ such that
$$
l(P+Q)=2.
$$
I know that if $D\in Div(C)$, and $x\in C$, then
$$
l(D)\leq l(D+x)\leq l(D)+1.
$$
According to this, if we consider $D=0$, we have that
$$
1\leq l(P+Q)\leq 3.
$$
How could we follow from here?

Comment: Hint : let $K$ be a canonical divisor. What is its degree ? Prove that $K$ is linearily equivalent to an effective divisor. Conclude.

Comment: @Roland Thanks! In this case, $d(K)=l(K)=2$. According to this, there exists $f\in\mathcal{L}(K)-\{ 0\}$, so there is an effective divisor $E$ such that $div(f)+D=E$. Taking degrees we see that $d(E)=2$. Since $E\geq 0$, $E=P+Q$ for certain $P,Q\in C$. Can we find them such that $P\neq Q$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for a full answer to your question "Can we find them such that $P\neq Q$ ?". Here is an argument which (should) work in characteristic $\neq 2$ and with $\operatorname{Card} k>5$  : with your divisor $E$, you have a degree 2 function $f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ with a pole of order 2 at $P$. Because it is not ramified everywhere, there exist $a\in k$ such that $f-a$ has two distinct zeros, say $A$ and $B$. But then $A+B$ is equivalent to $2P$ so we have $l(A+B)=2$

Comment: @Roland Yes, I have read that divisor induces a degree two function $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$, but I do not really understand why. Since $l(E)=2$, there exists a function $g$ such that $div(g)+E\geq 0$. It means that $g$ has at most poles at $P,Q$. How do we know that we can find $g$ such that it has those poles? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be a canonical divisor. We have $\operatorname{deg} K=2g-2=2$ and $l(K)=2$. In particular it is linearly equivalent to an effective divisor $E$. Because $E$ is effective of degree 2, it is of the form $E=P+Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are two not necessarily distinct points.

We will show that we can take $P$ and $Q$ distinct. So assume that $P=Q$.

Take any non constant section of $L(E)$, it can be seen of a rational map $f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ with poles at $P$ only and of order at most 2 by assumption. Note that $f$ has a pole since it is not constant, and it is of order 2 otherwise $f$ would be of degree 1, which contradict the fact that $C$ is not rational.

The map $f$ is not ramified everywhere (in characteristic $\neq 2$), this means that there exist $a\in k$ such that the fiber of $f$ at $a$ is two distinct points $A$ and $B$ (if $k$ is algebraically closed). Consider $f-a$ : $\operatorname{div}(f-a)=A+B-2P$, so that $2P$ is equivalent to $A+B$ and $l(A+B)=l(2P)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

As Roland says, $deg\ K=2g-2=2$. Also, by Riemann Roch, $h^0(C,K)-h^0(C,\mathcal{O})=2+1-2=1$. Hence $h^0(C,K)=2$, so $dim|K|=1$. Hence we can find an effective $D$ linearly equivalent to $K$.